# Echo count in php

Tags: php, sql, echo

I would like to ask how to echo the count from sql in php?

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) as total FROM visitor");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
Echo $row['total'];
```

Comment: you have to **fetch** your data first. `$row` is just a resource pointing to the results, from which you have to read first.

Comment: if its just the game of total record use `num_rows`

Comment: oh, and **don't** use `mysql_` functions anymore. they are deprecated and in PHP7, removed.

Comment: `print_r($row)` and add in question

Comment: @FranzGleichmann undefined function

Comment: @hihi *what* function? i didn't even write any function.

Comment: try like that, `$row = $sql->fetch_array();
echo $row['total'];` dont use mysql_* method, its deprecated and closed in php 7, and also this will work if you are using mysql_connect otherwise u are mixing mysql and mysqli

Comment: @BarneyStinson undefined function

Comment: what connections are u using mysql or mysqli?

Comment: i hope u got the solution now

Answer (score 3):

*First of all do not mix mysql_* *and mysqli extension together, you can't get anything by doing this.*

*Second, very important, mysql_* *is deprecated and closed in PHP 7, you can use mysqli_* *or PDO.*

**Here is the basic example with MYSQLi Objected Oriented:**

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($YourServerName, $Yourusername, $Yourpassword, $Yourdbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM Table";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    echo 'Total:'. $row[0]; // print total record
} 
else 
{
    // if record not exist.
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$row = $conn->query($sql);
$data = $row->fetch();
echo $data['total'];
```

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch()

Comment: u can use like `if(count($data) > 0){ echo $data['data']} else{echo 0;}`

Comment: Hmm ok, maybe you can try to use PDO instead of mysqli

Comment: @devpro  undefined method

Comment: @hihi: `$row = $sql->fetch_array();
echo $row['total'];`